# boto3 - using list_tags for an ElasticSearch resource with a valid arn causes ValidationException to be raised

Tags: python, elasticsearch, boto3

I have been working with the list_tags function for checking ElasticSearch domains, however, when providing valid ARN to the function, I'm seeing `botocore.errorfactory.ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListTags operation: Invalid ARN provided` where the ARN is of the form `arn:aws:es:us-west-1:acc_num:domain/es_name` - the ARN provided is valid, matching the domain name in the AWS Console.

Having debugged through the boto code, I noticed that in the function `prepare_request_dict` in the `awsrequest.py` file that the format of the ARN within the query string is being modified (within the `if r['query_string']:` section of the aforementioned file), converting the colons and forward slash to their ASCII code value. eg. ARN was becoming `arn%3Aaws%3Aes%3Aus-west-1%3Aacc_num%3Adomain%2Fes_name`.

Can't say I've noticed this with other functions within boto. I've tested obtaining the tags via the AWS console using `aws es list-tags --arn ARN`, and this works fine, with either single and double quotes for the ARN string. Have tested the same with the boto code, neither of which works, outputting the same ValidationException error message.

Code snippet for reference:

```
def get_es_tags(domain_arn) # where domain_arn='arn:aws:es:us-west-1:acc_num:domain/es_name'
   es_client = boto3.get_client('es')
   response = es_client.list_tags(ARN=domain_arn)
   ...
```

Currently using boto3 version 1.17.98, botocore version 1.20.98, with Python 3.8.